# Entropy of mixing identical gases

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, identical-particles

I think this is called [Gibbs paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox), but I am having some trouble understanding intuitively the entropy of mixing two identical gases in two volumes. It is said that after we remove the divider between two identical gases in identical volumes with number of particles, the entropy does not change. This comes from the fact that the particles are indistinguishable.

However, even if the particles are identical, don't we increase the number of possibilities for the particles to now occupy?

E.g., let’s say we have a partition and each side of the partition has two slots and there is a single particle in each side. *x* __ | *x* __

Before, we have 4 possibilities (*x* __ | *x* __ ; __ *x* | *x* __ ; __ *x* | __ *x* ; *x* __ | __ *x*).

After we remove the divider, we additionally have the possibilities where both the particles are on the same side (giving us 6 total possibilities).

Didn't the entropy increase?

Comment: Entropy does not change because it is defined to be extensive function of $N,V$ and additive for collection of systems. This is the reason to introduce the divisor $N!$ or $N^N$ in the Boltzmann formula. Definition of entropy has nothing to do with indistinguishability of particles in QT. Entropy is extensive and additive already in classical statistical mechanics, where particles are distinguishable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The situation is even worse in the case of non-interacting particles: there are four additional states due to the possibility of occupying a single slot with two particles. In total, $10$ states to be compared with the $4$ states in the presence of the divider.

However, these additional states do not contribute to an increase in the macroscopic thermodynamic entropy. The reason is that thermodynamic entropy can be obtained from statistical mechanics only in the limit of large systems (the so-called thermodynamic limit). In that limit the additional states do not contribute.

Indeed, let's indicate by $F(N,P)$ the number of microstates of $N$ identical particles which can be in $P$ different states. The change of entropy with respect to a system made by two equal subsystems of $N/2$ particles, each with $P/2$ states, can be obtained by taking the logarithm of the ratio $\frac{F(N,P)}{F(N/2,P/2)^2}$.

Now, $F(N,P)$ is exactly given by
$$
F(N,P)= \frac{(N+P-1)!}{N!(P-1)!}.
$$
For large $N$ and $P$ we can use the asymptotic [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):
$$
n! \simeq \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(  \frac{n}{e}   \right)^n
$$
to get
$$
F(N,P)\simeq \sqrt{\frac{N+P}{2 \pi N P}} \cdot \frac{(N+P)^{N+P}}{N^N P^P}
$$
(were I have neglected $1$ with respect to $P$ and $N+P$). With this approximate formula, we can evaluate the ratio between the number of microstates after and before the removal of the separation set:
$$
\frac{F(N,P)}{[F(N/2,P/2)]^2}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{N\cdot P}{N+P}}.
$$
The logarithm of such an expression multiplied by the Boltzmann constant is the entropy of mixing, and it is clearly positive. However, at the thermodynamic limit ($N\rightarrow \infty$), terms finite or proportional to $\ln N$ do not contribute to the macroscopic entropy.